# PHP multiple textbox array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have array of textbox

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="1234">
  <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="used">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="24">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="2345">
  <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="good">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="31">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="3456">
  <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="brand new">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="22">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

after posting, i want to insert to my database like this. with the same ref_id.

```
last_insert_id = 17;

id | ref_id | partnumber| description | quantity
1  | 17     | 1234      | used        | 24
2  | 17     | 2345      | good        | 31
3  | 17     | 3456      | brand new   | 22
```

any help will be appriciated. thanks..

```
$comma  = "";
$values = "";
$last_id = 17;
foreach ($partnumber as $p) {
    foreach ($desc as $d) {
       foreach ($qty as $q) {
        }
    }
     $values .= $comma."($id,$last_id,'$p','$d','$q')";
     $comma = ",";
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO parts_replaced (id,last_id,partnumber,description,quantity) VALUES $values";
```

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: I already update the question with my code but it seems that it's not the proper way :(

Answer (score 1):

you can get the out of this form like that..

```
 <form method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="1234">
          <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="used">
          <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="24">
          <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="2345">
          <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="good">
          <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="31">
          <input type="text" name="partnumber[]" value="3456">
          <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="brand new">
          <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="22">
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['partnumber']))
        {
        $parnumber=$_POST['partnumber'];

        foreach ($parnumber as $key => $value) {
            echo $value.'-'.$_POST['desc'][$key].'-'.$_POST['qty'][$key].'<br />';

//add your query here
        }

        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
extract($_POST);
$last_id = 17; 
foreach($partnumber as $key => $p ){  // Can use any of the mandatory field here
        $part_no = $p;
    $description = $desc[$key];
    $qty = $qty[$key];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO parts_replaced (`ref_id`,`partnumber`,`description`,`qty`) VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$part_no."','".$description."','".$qty ."') ";
    mysql_query($sql); // If id is auto incremented no need to specify it in query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The count of fields in your `INSERT INTO` do not match the count of values:

> $sql = "INSERT INTO parts_replaced
> (**id,last_id,part_no,description,qty**) VALUES $values";
>
> $values .= $comma."(**$id,'$p','$d','$q'**)";

Answer (score 0):

Make your html as below :

```
<?php $i=0;?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="1234">
  <input type="text" name="desc[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="used">
  <input type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="24">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[<?php echo $i+1;?>]" value="2345">
  <input type="text" name="desc[<?php echo $i+1;?>]" value="good">
  <input type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $i+1;?>]" value="31">
  <input type="text" name="partnumber[<?php echo $i+12;?>]" value="3456">
  <input type="text" name="desc[<?php echo $i+2;?>]" value="brand new">
  <input type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $i+2;?>]" value="22">
  <input type="hidden" name="arr_length" value="<?php echo $i+2;?>">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Handle in php as below :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['arr_length']) && $_POST['arr_length'] > 0){
        for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['arr_length'];$i++){
            echo $_POST['partnumber'][$i].'---'.$_POST['desc'][$i].'---'.$_POST['qty'][$i].'<br>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = "";
$last_id = 17;
$parnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
for($i=0, $max = count($parnumber); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $p = $_POST['parnumber'][$i];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'][$i];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
     $values .= "('$id','$last_id','$p','$desc','$qty'), ";
}
$str = trim($values);// trim the last white space
$str = rtrim($values, ',');//remove last comma

$sql = "INSERT INTO parts_replaced (id,last_id,part_no,description,qty) VALUES $str";
```